# ActiveMQ - is there a way to encrypt credentials.properties password values

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, securityexception

I have an issue trying to encrypt the password in the `credentials.properties` file which is used for browsing the queue messages on GUI console.
For authentication and authorization I followed [these steps](https://activemq.apache.org/security.html).
It seems that the default behaviour is to look for username and password in `credentials.properties` and by adding encrypted values it fails with:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [admin] or password is invalid.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1404)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1487)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:528)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.getConnection(WebClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.createSession(WebClient.java:359)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.getSession(WebClient.java:250)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.QueueBrowseQuery.getSession(QueueBrowseQuery.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.QueueBrowseQuery.createBrowser(QueueBrowseQuery.java:90)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.QueueBrowseQuery.getBrowser(QueueBrowseQuery.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [admin] or password is invalid.
        at org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationBroker.authenticate(SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java:103)
        at org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:853)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:336)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onCommand(ResponseCorrelator.java:116)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.iterate(VMTransport.java:275)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

Everything works fine in rest, producing messages, consuming messages, connecting with the encrypted passwords from `credentials-enc.properties` to the queue.
The only problem is that I want to hide the clear text values from `credentials.properties`.
If the password is in clear text it works.
I'm using ActiveMQ 5.16.1 installed on a
Red Hat 6.6 linux server.
Does somebody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

I've tried encrypting it with jetty-util MD5 and jasypt. Neither works.

Comment: The instructions you linked are for the broker's configuration. However, the stack-trace you pasted is from a _client_. Are you trying to mask passwords on the client or the broker?

Comment: Indeed there's an inconsistency in the stacktrace, sorry for that, I'm trying to mask the password on the broker, config file credentials.properties. To be honest there are not much information online related to this. Basically that file is related to the webconsole access.

Comment: You should update your question to clarify the issue. If you're not dealing with a client-side issue then I recommend removing the stack-trace from the client.